# Where does coingecko/coinmarketcap get the Max Supply of tokens?

Tags: erc-20

I am deploying a contract that will ultimately mint a total of 1,000,000 coins
Currently, only 100 were minted.

So the number that is returned from TotalSupply() is 100.
How do you expose the cap (max total supply) to sites like coingecko/etherscan/etc'?

Side question -
I see in some contracts that while there is a _cap parameter, it is not enforced in any way inside the mint function (and more than the cap can technically exist - if so, how can this figure be trusted without auditing each contract?)

Answer (score 0):

How many decimals do you set in your contract?

I think the number is 4 decimals so you should put the total supply amount + number of decimals (zeros) to get the right answer when you call `totalsupply()`

Comment: Isn't there a difference between TotalSuppply and Max Total Supply?